# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to myClass

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm working on a project where I have the following structure:

- (1) An API that holds some case classes, traits, and abstract classes.
- (2) Main Jar that uses API(1) as a dependency (API is published and used in the build.sbt as deps).
- (3) We have a need sometimes to create jars and load them in the main jar (2) using class utils during runtime, knowing that these jars also use API(1) as a dependency.

Now everything was working fine with the 3rd point which is about loading classes from the jar on runtime and making sure that these extend the API class correctly:
`clazz = classLoader.loadClass("name") return clazz.asInstanceOf[MyClass]`

But after I made a small change to MyClass in the API which was mainly about adding an implicit parameter to the signature of my abstract class, I can no longer identify the external jars (being loaded during runtime) and I keep getting the following error:

`[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to MyClass`

`[error] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to MyClass`

MyClass signature from the API looks something like this:
`abstract class MyClass (implicit val something: Type) extends AnotherClass {`

Any help to bypass this is appreciated guys. I can give more details if needed as well.
Thanks

Comment: Look at the compiled bytecode and see if something changed.

Comment: thnx for your answer but if you mean look at what changed from working version to the new one, I know what changed exactly which is adding the implicit value to the abstract class and the class part of the jar I'm loading on runtime.

Comment: There is no way how `clazz.asInstanceOf[MyClass]`  could possibly work under any circumstances, since `Class` is final. This casting does not make any sense, you probably wanted to cast an instance of the loaded class, not the class itself.

Comment: My bad thanks @AndreyTyukin. What you said is correct.